# FBConnect delegate methods not called IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I just downloaded the facebook connect from github and none of the delegate methods are being called.

I even noticed that they did not assign the facebook.sessiondelegate = self in the viewdidload method. Therefore i assigned it but still no delegate methods called. This is really worrying because I am trying to get some user data and none of the call back methods are called.
Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok basically if it does the authentication via Safari, there is no way to get call backs. One way to solve this is force the in app login by forcing the trysafariauth = no .

Comment: where do you set this property?

Comment: I set it in FBConnect's code - Facebook.m - is there a more proper place?